# Parse Error: Syntax Error, unexpected T_STRING in /server.php

Tags: php, database

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /server.php.
```

The line shows as follows;

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://awebsite.com/status?server_ip=<?=$s['ip'];?>&clean=true');
```

I believe I am getting this because of

```
<?=$s['ip'];?>
```

Are there any work arounds for the T_STRING in the first code as it is quite frustrating. I have looked all over the place and can't find much on this.

I am using a database to fetch IPs from other servers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up on string concatenation, or double quoted strings. Don't try to use `<?=` php tags when already in PHP code context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://awebsite.com/status?server_ip={$s['ip']}&clean=true");
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick reply. It didnt seem to work unfortunately i'm still getting a T_STRING syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using string concatenation:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://awebsite.com/status?server_ip='.$s['ip'].'&clean=true');
```

Also, for future reference read the following article on why underscores are not recommended for URLs

http://blog.woorank.com/2013/04/underscores-in-urls-why-are-they-not-recommended/